# similar matrices times another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given $A$ and $B$ are two similar matrices where $A$ is symmetric, thus diagionalizable. Now we know that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues.

I was wondering are $AC$ and $BC$ similar for any arbitrary $C$? ($C$ is kind of a white noise matrix.)

I tried to put $C$ into Jordan form and apply the definition of similar matrix, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Do you mean that $AC$ and $BC$ are similar for _some_ $C$ (clearly yes, take $C=I$), or that $AC$ and $BC$ are similar for _every_ $C$ -- clearly no, take $C=(^1{}_0)$, $A=(^1{}_2)$ and $B=(^2{}_1)$.

Comment: Thank you guys for the quick answer.

Comment: If $C$ is invertible then you can say $C^{-1}AC$ and $C^{-1}BC$ are similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why it should be, since $C$ does not undergo the same transformation that is used for converting $B$ into $A.$ For example, let $A$ and $B$ *both* be diagonal with the eigenvalues in slightly different order, so that their upper left entries are different. Let $C$ be a matrix with all zeroes except that it has $1$ in the upper left corner. Then $AC$ and $BC$ consist of all zeroes except that they have a (different) value in the upper left corner.